# C# WPF Multithreading with real-time PLC

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have an application that monitors bit states from external socket/Ethernet connections, known as a PLC device.

These states trigger database calls and UI updates, some of which require Modal dialogs, others require Modeless dialogs.

The issue is that the process needs to continually monitor even when a Modal dialog is displayed.

I have tried using a DispatcherTimer, but this will block when a Modal dialog is displayed. I understand the reason why.

I tried a standard Timer, but I get an exception stating something like 'Some UI components require the thread to run in STA mode.'

So I create a standard Thread and set the ApartmetState to STA. The thread runs just fine after adding DispatcherInvoke around the part of the processing loop that requires UI interaction, but whenever a Modal dialog box is displayed, the thread is blocked until the Modal dialog is closed.

Now I really do not want to get into inter-thread messaging and over-complicating the whole thing.

I have also tried putting the Modal dialog into its own thread whenever a Modal dialog is needed. Everything works fine and it was almost acceptable, but the owner window of the application is still accessible, essentially making the Modal dialog a Modeless dialog. I tried setting the IsEnabled flag on the owner window and at first I thought that would be okay, but it is still active when clicked and hides the dialog.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Incorporate your comment into the question post instead.

Comment: So, it the simpliest inter-thread messaging, like ConcurrentQueue<T>, not enough?

Comment: Dispatcher timers should not be impaired by modal dialogs.  When you call `ShowDialog`, your call stack is preserved, but a nested dispatcher loop executes until `ShowDialog` returns.  That's why you can continue processing layout and input events, among other things.  Timers ought to be included in those other things, unless an exception was explicitly carved out for them, which would surprise me.  However, if you show the modal dialog _while in your timer callback_, then that would block it from firing, as the callbacks are not reentrant.

Comment: I usually use MahApps metro for my windows, which has a very nice in-window dialog implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue! I reverted back to a standard Timer and was able to get around not requiring STA mode; this reguired another judicial placement of Dispatcher.Invoke.

Now everything works as I expect.

Comment: Beware the blocking `Dispatcher.Invoke` methods.  You can easily set yourself up for a deadlock.  You can also end up with a _very_ deep call stack.  `BeginInvoke` tends to be much safer.